# adding new functionality in existing PHP code

Tags: php, function, checkbox

I have been trying to figure this out. This is a code that is written from someone else long time ago, and now I have been asked to add some new functionality. 
In short, there is a form that submits to mysql db and generates pdf with filled fields. 
There is possibility to go back and to edit the form and re-create the pdf.

My task was to add two checkboxes in the form. Everything works nice, the checkbox value is sent to the database and the pdf file is created with the checkbox checked or unchecked.

However when I go back to edit the form the checkbox is always unchecked, it doesn't fetch the value from the DB.

So the existing code to fill in the form is as bellow. I see that there is text, textarea and select...How can I add here the checkbox? 
Thank you for your help!

```
function fillEoi($eoiFile, $oldPost="NULL") {
if (is_array($oldPost) && count($oldPost)>2) {
    $handle = fopen($eoiFile, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize ($eoiFile));
    fclose ($handle);

    $tempName = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
    $handle = fopen($tempName ,"w");

    $fileContent=explode("\n",$contents);

    foreach ($fileContent as $key => $item) {
        //Get fieldname;
        unset($fieldName);
        $fieldName=strrev(stristr(str_replace("/", "\/", $item),"DB_"));
        $fieldName=strrev(substr(strrchr($fieldName,"'"),1));

        // If is an input field
        if (stripos($item, "type='text'") && stripos($item, $fieldName)) {      
                //if (stristr($item, $fieldName))   
            //  $valueAdd=" value='".$oldPost[$fieldName]."'";
                $oldPost[$fieldName] = (strpos($item,'DB_INSUREDVALUE')) ? showValue($oldPost[$fieldName]) : $oldPost[$fieldName];
                $item=str_replace($fieldName, $fieldName."' value='".$oldPost[$fieldName]."",$item);
        } elseif (stripos($item, "</textarea>") && stripos($item, $fieldName)) {
            // If is an Textarea
                $item=str_replace("</textarea>", $oldPost[$fieldName]."</textarea>" , $item);
        } elseif ((stripos($item, $fieldName) && stripos($item, "<select"))) /* or $selectField==1)*/   {
            $returnVar['EoiDate'][$fieldName]=$oldPost[$fieldName];
    }

        }


        $fileContent[$key]=$item;
    }
    $newContent=implode("\n",$fileContent);
    fwrite ($handle, $newContent);
    fclose($handle);
    $newEoiFile=$tempName;
    unset($eoiFile);
} else {
    $newEoiFile=$eoiFile;
}
$returnVar['EoiPath']=$newEoiFile;
return $returnVar;
```

}

Comment: In the code posted, I can not see where you generate the checkbox markup

Comment: In another php file is the html form. This is the part with the checkboxes. 
   `Weight: <input type='text' maxlength='60' size='24' name='DB_WEIGHT'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='DB_KGS'>KGS
     <input type='checkbox' name='DB_CARATS'>Carats`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a checkbox element to checked by using the checked attribute

```
// Get the checkbox state from db, I assume here it is checked
$checked = 1;

if ($checked) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="DB_KGS" checked="checked">';
} else {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="DB_KGS">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankrates. I am not sure that this is helpful, as I need to include it in the function above fillEOI, because this is the function that is called when editing the form.